# Enforcing interface implementation in order to use another class

Tags: java, interface

**SITUATION:** Say there is a class A and an interface B.

**REQUIREMENT:** If any class, say C, wants to create objects of A and use them, then that class will also have to implement interface B.Is there any way to enforce this condition?

**WHY:** Now a question may arise as to why I want to do such a thing. The reason is that when a class C creates objects of A and uses them, then those objects call certain methods of C. I want to declare those methods in interface B, so that C will invariably implement those methods.

Comment: Please elaborate the question to be more concrete. `A`, `B` and `C` are too abstract for us to grasp the point of what you're trying to do. What are your classes/interfaces _really_ called? As it stands, your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I have a class called Agent and an interface AgentInterface. Now any class(these classes will be written by others, not by me) which wants to make use of agents will have to create an object of Agent, right? But I want to enforce a condition here. I also want that class to implement the AgentInterface if it has to make use of the class Agent.Is it possible to enforce such a condition? If not, in what way can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: Mukherjee: I still don't understand your design. What methods does the `AgentInterface` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that objects of class `A` will call methods on `C`, they will have to keep reference to `C` somehow. Make this reference of type `B` and you are done.

That is

```
public class A {
  public A(B arg) {
     ....
  }
}
```

Then in `C`:

```
A a = new A(this);
```

That will force class C to implement interface `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
public interface B {
// methods
}
```

---

```
public class A {
   private final B b;
   public A(B b) {
      this.b = b;
   }  
  ...
}
```

---

```
public class C implements B{
   // implement B's methods
   public static void main(String[] arg) {
        C c = new C();
        A a = new A(c);
   }

}
```